# ArcGIS Online Feature Style Using Multiple Attributes

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, style, fields-attributes

I am configuring style for a line feature in ArcGIS Online. I used one string field to define the line style and want to use another string field to define the color. However the second attribute is not in the drop-down list. Is there any requirement for attribute field to be used as a second option for styling? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are certain requirements on the fields being used. Like Color and Size will require 2 numeric attributes same with Compare A & B. If you mention the way you want to style your layer I can add additional info in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Russ! Basically we have two fields both are Short Integer. We used to use the first one for style and we styled it as solid lines/dashed lines in same color. Now we would like to add the second field as a color style(say red or green) to display but I cannot see the second field in the list when adding a second attribute.

Comment: I just found that as long as the first attribute has a domain assigned, only those attributes without a domain will show up in the second attribute pick list, regardless of the field type. I am not sure if this is true but both of the two attributes we use has a domain.